# The version needs to be updated

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

```
// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the proto package it is being compiled against.
// A compilation error at this line likely means your copy of the
// proto package needs to be updated.
const _ = proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3 // please upgrade the proto package
```

I can't start my app on MacOS. The version of **protoc** I've been using: 3.6.1. 
It fails and says:

```
undefined: proto.ProtoPackageIsVersion3
```

in every self-generated ***.pb.go** file.

What can I do?

Comment: You're supposed to do what it says in the comment. Update the github.com/golang/protobuf/proto package. You simply can't use code generated by protoc 3.6 with an old runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The comment is a bit unclear,

You should update https://github.com/golang/protobuf, but the tricky part here is that release v1.2.0 doesn't contain new changes for v3.6.1. You can use `master` branch in this case.

Comment: how do you workaround this? I want to use protobuf 2.